# how do i download an image from a link?

Tags: html, firebase, vue.js, download

I am trying to download an image when the user clicks on the button but when i click on the button the image opens in the browser instead of only downloading it. The link is an image from firebase. Any one that knows what i am doing wrong of has a solution for me?

```
<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/q-aviationdev.appspot.com/o/4%2F98906.jpg?alt=media&token=e19f9317-79c7-46d2-a758-40309b4c4f0f" download="Testiamge.jpg">
     <b-button size="sm"  @click="downloadImg(index)" class="mr-2">
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'download' ]" />
    </b-button>
    </a>
```

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I found the document here, you can reference [Download Files on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use this part:

```
<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/q-aviationdev.appspot.com/o/4%2F98906.jpg?alt=media&token=e19f9317-79c7-46d2-a758-40309b4c4f0f" download="Testiamge.jpg">
    <img alt="ImageName" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/q-aviationdev.appspot.com/o/4%2F98906.jpg?alt=media&token=e19f9317-79c7-46d2-a758-40309b4c4f0fe">
</a>
```

If you want to use a button, you can try this code:

```
<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/q-aviationdev.appspot.com/o/4%2F98906.jpg?alt=media&token=e19f9317-79c7-46d2-a758-40309b4c4f0f" download> 
    <button>Download image</button> 
</a>
```

If you are using IE, try this one:

```
<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/q-aviationdev.appspot.com/o/4%2F98906.jpg?alt=media&token=e19f9317-79c7-46d2-a758-40309b4c4f0f" download target="_blank">Download image</a>
```

Comment: this doesn't work instead of downloading it, it just opens in de browser